# How is a version of Bitcoin marked as 'obsolete'

Tags: protocol

I'm compiling a pre-release version of a Bitcoin based altcoin.  I get a temporary connection to a current version fullnode of my own, but the connection is then rejected.

When I look in the debug.log of the current version node, it says the new protocolversion is obsolete, but the new version is higher than the current one.

I'm trying to understand how these mechanisms work, thank you.

EDIT for clarity: How does protocol version come into being, how is obsoleteness determined, why whould a higher version show as obsolete?

Comment: You have a bug in your code. Point.

Comment: Yes probably, but how does the protocolversion mechanism work?  How does it decide what is obsolete, why might a higher version qualify as obsolete? That is the question.

Comment: How does your code work? Nobody knows except of you.

Comment: Im asking about the standard Bitcoin code, so then I can attempt to look at this code and try and understand what might be different about it, thats why the title is: "How is a version of Bitcoin marked as 'obsolete'".

Comment: So the version is stored at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/version.h